# Django Rest Framework + django_filters on serialized values

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm trying to filter on a serialized value that is not on my model but I can't get my head around this.

Here is my **model.py** :

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_id_number=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    variable_1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    variable_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    variable_3 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Here is my **Views.py** :

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PostSerializers
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    filterset_class = PostFilter
```

Here is my **serializers.py**:

```
class PostSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    variable_not_in_the_model = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('post_id_number',
            'variable_1', 
            'variable_2', 
            'variable_3', 
            'variable_not_in_the_model',
            )

    def get_variable_not_in_the_model(self, instance):
        return instance.variable_1 + ' ' + instance.variable_2 + ' ' + instance.variable_3
```

Here is my actual **filters.py** :

```
from .models import Post
import django_filters

class PostFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = {
            'variable_1': ['icontains'],
            'variable_2': ['icontains'],
            'variable_3': ['icontains']
        }
```

Here is what I would like my **filters.py** to look like but it doesn't work :

```
from .models import Post
import django_filters

class PostFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = {
            'variable_not_in_the_model': ['icontains']
        }
```

Is there a way I can Filter on the serialized variables and not on the model's variables ?

Thanks so much for your help !

Comment: The filtering process is happening in the database level, against the existing DB fields (or annotated fields). So, you can't do filtering against *non-model fields*

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that !

Answer (score 0):

You can't use values from the serializer in the filter. The filter works on the model/db fields. But you can build the custom queryset yourself. If you just want to check if the value is in one of the first three variables, you can try this:

```
import django_filters

from .models import Post


class PostFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    search = django_filters.CharFilter(method='filter_search')

    class Meta:
        model = Post

    def filter_search(self, qs, name, value):
        if value:
            return qs.filter((
                Q(variable_1__icontains=value) |
                Q(variable_2__icontains=value) |
                Q(variable_3__icontains=value)
            ))
        return qs
```

and then add the `?search=something` query param in your API call

Comment: Thanks so much. I had problems when trying to add it this way as a filter, but succed but creating a ListAPIView dinstinct from my actual viewset and using almost exactly what you explained. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I was able to do :

In my **views.py** I created a new View (not sure it's ideal since I had to create a new url but since I was using a viewset I wasn't able to to that differently)

```
class PostAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostSerializers

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #queryset_list = super(PostAPIView, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        queryset_list = Post.objects.all()
        query = self.request.GET.get("q")
        if query:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
                Q(variable_1__icontains=query) |
                Q(variable_2__icontains=query) |
                Q(variable_3__icontains=query)
            ).distinct()
        return queryset_list
```

In my **urls.py** I've added :

```
path('api/filter/', PostAPIView.as_view(), name='test'),
```

And it's working...Not sure it's optimal but working.

Thanks for your help !!!